# how to write results of CRF++ tool in a file

Tags: file-writing, crf++

I am using CRF++. 
The following command is used for testing:-

```
crf_test -m model_file test_files
```

There is no option to write results on file. While we need results on separate file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

`crf_test -m model_file test_files>filename`. Hope this is helpful.